# Retry requests from an API that returns errors

Tags: python, pandas, api

I am requesting data from an API that returns back end errors occasionally. I have a list of identifiers that I hand to the apifunction by index to retrieve its respective data. The returned dataframe is stored.

```
x=0
while x <= 13000:
    file_checked = Path("path\\%05d.pkl" % (x))

    if file_checked.is_file():
        print(str(x) + list_of_identifiers[x])
        x += 1

    else:
        identifier = list_of_identifiers[x]
        data = apifunction

        data.to_pickle("path\\\\%05d.pkl" % (x))
        print(str(x) + list_of_identifiers[x])
        x += 1
```

The print command just gives me visual feedback on the progression. Checking if the file exists makes it easier for me to restart the loop as I don't have to set the x manually when my loop breaks.

And this is my big problem. The loop breaks. Occasionally the server returns back end errors of various different types (maybe around three different error codes).

Can someone help me to make this code (or alternative ways) robust to the mentioned errors? It should simply retry the same "x" and afterwards proceed. I should mention that from my experience the errors seem to occur arbitrarily which makes it highly unlikely that one could get stuck in an endless loop of retries.
Although I have found several posts on this topic, I was not able to transfer it to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can someone comment on my current solution:

```
x=0
while x <= 13073:
    file_checked = Path("path\\%05d.pkl" % (x))

    if file_checked.is_file():
        x += 1

    else:
        while x <= 13073:
            try:
                identifier  = list_of_identifiers[x]
                data = apifunction
                data.to_pickle("path\\%05d.pkl" % (x))
                x += 1
            except:
                print("Error")
                continue
```